# pointer to array of pointers in Tree-like class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a major problem with pointers in C/C++. I'm trying to implement a tree-like structure with nodes. Each node has a pointer to another array of pointers to other nodes.

Here is my Node struct:

```
struct Node
{
    int key_value;
    bool is_init = false;
    Node* children;
};
```

My problem appears to be somewhere in these lines

```
bool flag = false;
Node *temp = &(root->children[mod]);
while (!flag)
{
    mod = key % k;
    if (temp->children[mod].is_init != false)
    {
        if (temp->children[mod].key_value != key)
        {
            temp = &(temp->children[mod]);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d exsist\n", key);
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        temp->children = new Node[k];
        temp->children[mod].is_init = true;
        temp->children[mod].key_value = key;
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

By reading error messages I think it's because children below the root level do not point to other node array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x010D9D15 in AisdSparseTable.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDDD.   it breaks in the   if (temp->children[mod].is_init != false) line

Comment: I think you may find this interesting: [Magic Debug Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values).

Comment: @notFluentinC `temp->children = new Node[k]; temp->children[mod].is_init = true;`  Either `temp` is invalid, or `mod >= k` making that an invalid access.  Please debug your code.

Comment: Your "array" is not an array of pointers, but an array of nodes. The signature should be `Node**`

Comment: And fyi, this algorithm looks terribly broken.The obliteration (and likely memory leak) of the else clause in this makes no sense. I see nowhere that the actual `children` allocated magnitude is managed.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use `bool is_init = false;` in a structure, even in C++.

Comment: I guess i'll just try to rewrite it properly. Thanks for help&tips everyone.

Comment: Based solely off the fact the code contains `new Node[k]`, the C tag has been dropped.

Answer (score 0):

The code is incomplete for finding the error. You might want to modify your structure to something like this in order to keep track of the number of structures allocated:

```
 struct Node 
   {
       int key_value;
       bool is_init = false;
       Node* children;
       int len;
   };
```

and add a check here:

```
if (temp->len > mod && temp->children[mod].is_init != false)
{ ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are creating new nodes is wrong. You are creating new array of nodes only when you don't find `temp->children[mod].is_init != false` but not when its null. Probably a NULL check before existing condition should fix it.

OR

```
 temp = &(temp->children[mod]);
```

Check if children exist before assigning it to temp

Comment: that sound very reasonable. I'll try checking it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To start off...
***Change:***

```
struct Node
{
    int key_value;
    bool is_init = false;//illegal initialization in C
    Node* children;
};
```

***To:***

```
struct Node
{
    int key_value;
    bool is_init;
    Node* children;
};  
typedef struct Node NODE;
```

Then you can create and initialize like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    NODE *head = {0}, *first = {0}, *temp = {0};
    head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    head->key_value = 10;
    head->is_init = 0;
    if(first != 0)
    {
        temp->children = head;
        temp = head;
    }
    else
    {
        first = temp = head; //save location of first item
    }
    // etc., etc.
    // ...
```